# Подскажите слайдер или принцип JS JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Есть такой слайдер:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Суть его такова что при клике на слайд (синий блок) он становится в центр. Зеленый блок это картинка слайда, которая подставляется при клике. Красный блок это подробный текст слайда.

Когда мы нажимаем на элемент картинка, подробный текст меняются. Так же все элементы строятся в числовой последовательности. К примеру мы кликнули на первый элемент - Он встал в центр, последовательность слайдеров такая - `5, 6, 7, 1 (выбранный), 2, 3, 4`.
Подскажите как такое сделать? или может есть готовое решение.

Спасибо.

Comment: Делал что-то подобное с использованием http://www.jssor.com/ но не факт что вам подойдет

Comment: @programmer403 штука в том что тут картинки, а у меня контент который нужно изменять.

Comment: набросок - http://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/VpxOxW?editors=1010

Comment: @Elena что-то похожее. ещё фигня в том что активный слайд должен быть всегда по центру. Кнопок вперед назад нет. по клику. Спасибо.